# Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'NSObject' and 'String'

Tags: swift, fetch, uisearchbar, binary-operators

I am trying to search users on a UITableView, through a UISearchBar. The thing is that an error keeps appearing when I try to.

Here's my code:

```
 var isSearching = false
 func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText:String) {
     if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
        isSearching = false
        view.endEditing(true)
        searchTableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        isSearching = true
        filteredUsers = users.filter({$0 == searchBar.text!})  // error appears here

    }

    searchTableView.reloadData()
}
```

I am trying to search for the users in my app, through Firebase fetch. I've already fetched the users onto a UITableView, the thing is I cant search for a specific one. Please help! I've tried everything.

Comment: post declaration of array users

Answer (score 2):

A type `NSObject` can't compared with a type of `String` , you need

```
filteredUsers = users.filter({$0.someProperty == searchBar.text!})
```

where `someProperty` is a property inside the class

Comment: Any ideas on which property I could use?

Comment: on the property you want to search in according to the searchBar text